# Compilation error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, llvm, clang

`clang/llvm` does not compile in `Visual Studio 2010`.
I have done everything how it is described here [Getting Started: Building and Running Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) (section Using Visual Studio).
And I get the nest errors:

> *Error 922 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'llvm/Intrinsics.gen'*

and so on.
They say that it is because `TableGe` has not been compiled.
So I have tried to compile it separately. And by this time I get

```
linking error: *error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl llvm::sys::StrError(int)"*
```

and so on.
And as result: `*fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals*.`
These files

> ....\lib\Debug\LLVMTableGen.lib
>   ....\lib\Debug\LLVMSupport.lib

are presented.
If anyone faced with the similar problem, then how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling from trunk? The LLVM/Clang trunk is always in flux and sometimes you may catch it not fully functional, especially on Windows which is not a 1st-order concern for most LLVM developers.

If you don't terribly care about the newest LLVM possible, I suggest you download and build the 3.1 release which should work on all platforms. If you want a more recent release but not the cutting-edge trunk, try checking out the 3.2 release branch. It wasn't formally released yet, but it's currently in the stabilization phase so there's a very good chance it will successfully build on Windows if you follow the instructions.